# example of a for-while loop to go from a list of nodes to a reachability matrix or a graph of transitively associated nodes and edges?

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, transitive-closure

I'm a beginner! I'm trying to code a for-while loop using [Twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/) to scrape Twitter, starting from a list or a dict of usernames and ending up with a ([NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/)) directed graph of transitively associated nodes and edges. I want to set a variable number of transitive steps until transitive closure. 'Directed' will refer to whether the follower/followed relationship is one way or both ways.

I've tried and I've got a For loop which outputs edges, and a While loop which outputs additional transitively associated nodes into a list, but the While loop doesn't output edges yet.

Please can someone point me to a relevant example of how to do this or part of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It will be much easier if we can see your existing code.  To enter it, click on the 'edit' button and copy-paste them (putting blank lines above and below)  Then highlight the block of code and (on a mac) the shortcut command-k will intent it all once, which will cause it to be formatted like code.